# SAM Lambda: [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'pg8000'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, sam

I've deployed a lambda (python3.7) which uses pg8000

```
import pg8000
..
def get_connection():
    """
        Method to establish the connection.
    """
    try:
        print ("Connecting to database")
        # Create a low-level client with the service name for rds
        client = boto3.client("rds")
        # Read the environment variables to get DB EndPoint
        DBEndPoint = os.environ.get("DBEndPoint")
        # Read the environment variables to get the Database name
        DatabaseName = os.environ.get("DatabaseName")
        # Read the environment variables to get the Database username which has access to database.
        DBUserName = os.environ.get("DBUserName")
        # Generates an auth token used to connect to a db with IAM credentials.
        password = client.generate_db_auth_token(
            DBHostname=DBEndPoint, Port=5432, DBUsername=DBUserName
        )
        # Establishes the connection with the server using the token generated as password
        conn = pg8000.connect(
            host=DBEndPoint,
            user=DBUserName,
            database=DatabaseName,
            password=password,
            ssl={"sslmode": "verify-full", "sslrootcert": "rds-ca-2015-root.pem"},
        )
        print("Succesful connection!")
        return conn
    except Exception as e:
        print ("While connecting failed due to :{0}".format(str(e)))
        return None
...
```

I have a requirements.txt which contains:

```
pg8000==1.13.2
boto3==1.9.67
```

I'm performing a sam build, sam package and sam deploy. Does sam build not handle the download of dependencies like pg8000?

Exact commands:

```
sam build
sam package --template-file ./template.yml --output-template-file output.yml --s3-bucket xxx-bucket
sam deploy --template-file ./output.yml --stack-name demo --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Error after triggering lambda:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'pg8000'
```

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your error?

Comment: I'll try tonight! Thanks already for the input.

Answer (score 5):

According to doc

> **sam build**
>   looks for a manifest file (such as requirements.txt) that contains the
>   dependencies, and automatically creates deployment artifacts.

It seems like your modules haven't been deployed at all.

I'll explain how to fix it step by step:

- `sam build` created a folder `.aws-sam/build` with your lambda function in it including dependencies and one more very important file: your **use this** `template.yml` with `CodeUri` (path to lambdas src code) relative to `.aws-sam/build` folder.
- `sam package` command should pass the location of your `template.yml` as argument, meaning **sam build** destination folder url . run `sam package --template-file .\.aws-sam\build\template.yml --output-template-file .\.aws-sam\build\output.yml --s3-bucket your_bucket`
- Finally run `sam deploy --template-file .\.aws-sam\build\output.yml  --stack-name demo --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

When you executed this command: `sam package --template-file ./template.yml --output-template-file output.yml --s3-bucket xxx-bucket`
,template file `./template.yml` point to your lambda funcion without the dependencies which are located in  `.\.aws-sam\build\your_lambda.`

One more thing:

If you are using multiple modules you should consider using [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Hope this helps